# Не корректно отражается блок и ссылки на соц сети

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

разместил на своем сайте блок "Поделиться" но... возникло три проблемы:
1. Первая и последняя иконка отражается не корректно (моб версия https://yadi.sk/i/X97fuLJgp6lVsg) (версия ПК: https://yadi.sk/i/dv2X3alLHUnEDw)
2. При наведении курсора мыши курсор не определяет ссылку а распознает как картинку (наводить нужно на край иконки)
3. При клике на иконку к примеру в "вконтакте" открывается окно "фэйсбука" и т.д
Вопрос: как устранить данные проблемы? сайт кроме данного фактора работает на ура
Браузеры: Все браузеры обновлены до последней версии проблема наблюдается во всех браузерах начиная от IE до Мозилы 
Ссылка на пример: http://adionis.ru/the-top-5-defense-tactics-for-dwi-case/